# List comprehension with boolean (Python)

Tags: python, list, nested, boolean, list-comprehension

How to present this code as a list comprehension:

```
def all_targets_hit(attempts: list) -> bool:

    for ls in range(len(attempts)):
        if not any(attempts[ls]):
            return False
    return True

attempts =([
            [True, False, False],
            [False, False, True],
            [False, False, False, False],
        ])
```

#Expected: False

Comment: That code is not right.  It's only going to look at the first row, because you always `return`.  `ls` will never get past 0.  What do you want this to do?

Comment: @Tim Roberts Sorry, indentation error, corrected. I just need a solution in one row

Comment: `return all(any(attempt) for attempt in attempts)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine `all` with `any`:

```
def all_targets_hit(attempts: list) -> bool:
    return all([any(sublist) for sublist in attempts])

attempts =([
            [True, False, False],
            [False, False, True],
            [False, False, False, False],
        ]) 

all_targets_hit(attempts)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I need smth like/ return all(any(ls) for ls in attempt for attempt in attempts) / as list comprehension. But it seems doesn`t work

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But I need smth like `return all(any(ls) for ls in attempt for attempt in attempts)`  as list comprehension. But it doesn`t work with one list of attempts: 'bool' object is not iterable

Comment: Now all is ok, thanks again!